How do I use other views in IDEA profiler?
I open .jfr file in IntelliJ IDEA and start analyzing it.
I open "Events" tab: "Operating System" -> "Processor" -> "Thread CPU Load"
I get the following message in IntelliJ IDEA profiler:

This view shows only the first 200 events. Use other views to analyze the complete information.


How do I "use other views" in IDEA profiler?
